# mac osx app - swift window & viewcontroller fullscreen/resize

Tags: macos, swift2

I am trying to work out how windowcontroller and viewcontroller can talk to each other when the user clicks on the windowcontroller fullscreen or manually resizes the screen.

I have uploaded the full code to my github, as I am noob at swift and I am not sure what parts of the script you will need.

but here is part of the code

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  slither.io
//
//  Created by Russell Harrower on 1/06/2016.
//  Copyright © 2016 Russell Harrower. All rights reserved.
//
import Cocoa
import WebKit
class ViewController: NSViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var webView:WKWebView!

    override func viewWillAppear() {
        super.viewWillAppear()
        preferredContentSize = view.fittingSize
    }

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        //let webViewConfiguration: WKWebViewConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        let webView: WKWebView = WKWebView(frame:self.view.frame)
        let urlString = NSURL(string:"http://slither.io")
        let requestObj = NSURLRequest(URL: urlString!)

        webView.loadRequest(requestObj)
        self.view.addSubview(webView)

        //self.webView.mainFrame.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: urlString)!))
    }

    override var representedObject: AnyObject? {
        didSet {
        // Update the view, if already loaded.
        }
    }
}
```

you can see full xcodeproject at https://github.com/russellharrower/Slither.io-Mac-App

Answer (score 0):

Set your constrains of the webview be as super view. (I have set the web view with the constrains in the storyboard but sure you can do it in run time too)